# AngularJS: conditional ng-class with a function triggering ridiculous amounts

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

> I checked similar Q&As but they didn't fix my issue.

I want to dynamically set the class of an input, consider the following [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hxpMG3d9wHkc0Rrvsp6K?p=preview).

As you can see I have one field, defined like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="Person.Name" ng-class="{'mandatory': IsFieldMandatory('Name')}" />
```

That function has the following code:

```
self.IsFieldMandatory = function(field){
  var isMandatory = true;

  var value = $scope.Person.Name;

  $scope.Cnt = $scope.Cnt + 1;

  return value.length == 0;
}
```

As you can see, it triggers 11(!) times on a page load (or any further action like blur).

PS: The function does not work because I get this error:

```
Error: $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop
```

It occurs because of the $scope.Cnt increment. If put in comment, it works (but then I don't know the number of triggers).

PPS:

How can I use this?:

```
var value = $parse('Person.' + field);
```

That would be better because then the function would work for any field. Which it needs to, in the real world scenario. (*this returns a function, not an actual value*)

Thx!

**UPDATE**

The Plunkr example doesn't seem to be valuable, so instead the original function:

```
self.IsMandatory = function (field) {

    console.log('test');

    if (self.IsMandatoryFieldsLoaded == true) {
        var idxAsync = self.MandatoryFields.indexOf(field);
        return idxAsync > -1;
    }

    return false;
}
```

As you can see I don't do any modifications, just reads. I have 11 fields, yet this function's 'test' logging is written 198 times!

Comment: `var value = $scope.Person[field]` will be enough. And yes, you shouldn't update your model (`$scope` object) in the watch functions, as each such change basically triggers another invocation of watchers.

Comment: The error is caused by `$scope.Cnt = $scope.Cnt + 1;` if you remove the line it will only execute 2 times

Comment: Looks like that value works. How do you mean 'update model in watch function'? I'm only reading values, not setting any (forgetting the cnt for the example).

Comment: Of course, if you don't work with `$scope.cnt`, you only read values, and there's no 'ridiculous amounts' of digest calls.

Comment: Obviously the Plunkr isn't a valid testcase, please review the above update.

Comment: @Spikee - I checked the plunker code and it seems you want to validate field based on some condition . may be you should try ng-required

Comment: A conditional ng-required may be an alternative, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check if there is anything typed in the input like so:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="Person.Name" ng-class="{'mandatory': !Person.Name.length}" />
```

This way you get rid of your error. Because you were updating the `Cnt` $scope variable in your function, the digest cycle was triggered over and over again. That caused the infinite loop (the error you were seeing).

By simply checking if `Person.Name` has a length, you avoid declaring a new function and other unnecessary logic. It's simple and much cleaner.

Hope this helped.

**Update using ngForms:**

You can declare a directive for validating your input like so:

```
app.directive('validate', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
      scope.$watch('Person.Name', function(newValue) {
        ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('notEmpty', isEmpty(newValue))
      });
    }
  }
});

function isEmpty(string) {
  return !!string.length;
}
```

and use it on your input

```
<input type="text" validate ng-model="Person.Name"/>
```

and in your CSS you will have

```
input.ng-invalid {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Now you can delcare how many and complex validation functions and simply use the `$setValiditity()` function to tell Angular if that input is valid or not. If one of your validation will turn false, then Angular will automatically turn your input red by adding the `ng-invalid` class.

Comment: It would/does work in a yes/no condition, but I need to do pretty complex checks, which will mean I will have many possible classes. This wouldn't cover that.

Comment: Then `ngForm` can come in handy. You can add a $watch on your ngModel and delcare a custom validation function. Here's a pretty detailed article on how to do input/form validation in angularjs: http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/validations.html

Comment: And based on that validation function, angular will automatically add a `ng-invalid' class on your input. And you can style that class with a red border if you wish