# AngularJS: Error with remove- and addClass: c.attr is not a function

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

**Background**

I need to do custom form validation based on complex business rules. I will show this validation to the user by changing classes dynamically, (likely) using multiple classes that are meaningful to the user.

See my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439287/angularjs-conditional-ng-class-with-a-function-triggering-ridiculous-amounts/32439543?noredirect=1#comment52743658_32439543).

As it seems that ng-class is unreliable (runs too often), I'm looking into alternatives. And, it's actually not a bad thing to do the whole validation at a top level, then I can make sure I do just one backend call only (whenever necessary).

Another requirement is, I don't want/can't use jQuery, because the form may occur several times, since jQuery is not scope aware, this will not (easily) work (and, the cleaner the better).

**Plunkr tryout**

Consider this [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gL65cOTkjVBimkgPsiq4?p=preview) example.

**The question**

The above plunkr uses $animate.removeClass and $animate.addClass to dynamically change classes, but it results in this error:

```
TypeError: c.attr is not a function
    at angular.js:4907
    at m (angular.js:336)
    at angular.js:4904
    at n.a.$get.n.$digest (angular.js:15803)
    at n.a.$get.n.$apply (angular.js:16024)
    at angular.js:1658
    at Object.e [as invoke] (angular.js:4473)
    at d (angular.js:1656)
    at yc (angular.js:1676)
    at Zd (angular.js:1570)
```

*I get a similar error in the actual code, but there it's on the element (no minification?)*:

```
TypeError: element.attr is not a function
    at angular.js:4886
    at forEach (angular.js:336)
    at angular.js:4883
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:15735)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:15953)
    at done (angular.js:10366)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:10538)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:10479)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$elem.find returns dom elements - you will have to wrap each return in angular.element() - I have updated the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/8jkkXirjCFu5RpCcIiml?p=preview

```
var subElement = angular.element(input); // Update
var isRequired = $scope.IsMandatoryField(input.id);

if (isRequired == true){
    // Remove the default class.
    $animate.removeClass(subElement, "defaultClass");
    // Add required class.
    $animate.addClass(subElement, 'requiredClass');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for imperative `addClass` here, use `ng-class="{ 'someClass' : someInput.required }"`

Comment: I don't want to use ng-class, see background information.

Answer (score 0):

here you are:

http://plnkr.co/edit/xTejZKVj90zmO7yN9Ol6?p=preview

you need use a `angular.element` to select a element ;)