# AngularJS: How to get a DOM element by id

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, dom

**Sample**

Please consider this [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tkWcBFWCgVLpIDjJ3une?p=preview).

**What I need**

I need to be able to get an element by it's id.

The sample code should be able to assign a css class to any DOM element that exists on the current view.

This should be checked using a source object, provided by the $scope in a controller. This source object may/will have more properties than there are input elements on the view.

So I want to loop through each object key and see if a corresponding DOM element exists. If so, validate it's value.

**The question**

How do I get an element by id, using AngularJS only (jQuery is NOT allowed!!)?

Specifically for the Plunkr, I need this function to (really) work:

```
self.IsFieldCurrentlyActive = function(field){
  // Should be (in pseudocode):
  // var inputElement = angular.find(field);
  // return (inputElement != 'undefined');

  // Sample only
  var idx = field.indexOf('Unused');
  return idx == -1;
};
```

And this one (basically the same):

```
self.GetElementByKey = function(key)
{
  // Should be (in pseudocode):
  // var inputElement = angular.find(field);
  // return inputElement;

  // Sample only
  return null;
}
```

**Update**

Apologies, I forgot to add an important requirement: I can't use any mechanism that assumes unique IDs, because there may be multiple occurrences of the same form (and the same IDs). So, I need to respect the Angular scope.

Thanks!

Comment: What you want to achieve ? just assign a class to element ?

Comment: methinks you doing something wrong if you need use dom manipulation in factory or controller, try see [“Thinking in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background?rq=1)

Comment: As @Grundy said this is not angular way of doing things . Consider controller,directives for DOM manipulation.

Comment: Agree with the above comments. Try to take advantage of Angular's bindings instead of trying to do direct DOM manipulation.

Comment: @Ajinder: Basically yes, just the class.

Re factory/controller: Thanks for the link, I know, I have that exact problem :). But, I chose to use a service because that functionality will be shared by other directives.

Comment: @Spikee Consider using ng-class for conditionally assigning classes to element. Check https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: @Spikee - you can move the conditional logic to service and manipulate the element via directives

Comment: @Ajinder: I moved away from ng-class because of this issue: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439287/angularjs-conditional-ng-class-with-a-function-triggering-ridiculous-amounts)

Comment: @Spikee, so, you moved away from ng-class becuase used it wrong? :-)

Comment: Possibly :). Though, I tested it, and it runs multiple times even with very simple scenarios. Let's just say I keep my options open right now ...

Answer (score 14):

In pure JS you can do `document.querySelector('#myID');`

Or within angular using angular.element:
`angular.element(document.querySelector('#myID'));`

Comment: Depending on the browsers that you want support it's better to use [document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). `querySelector` is only supported in modern browsers.

Comment: Sadly this wont work because there may be multiple occurrences of the same form (and the same id), so I need to stay in (Angular) scope.

Comment: An Id should be unique. http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: Like I said, there's no way to guarantee it, and providing a mechanism that would force unique ids would make state-management very hard considering the complexity.

Comment: Actually, I found a possible solution that would be doable: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655009/how-to-set-the-id-attribute-of-a-html-element-dynamically-with-angular-js).

Comment: If your IDs are not unique, your DOM is not valid and browsers may react in unpredictable ways. Fix that first, before addressing this question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead try `angular.element($('#myElement'));`

Comment: The $('#myElement') part means you're using jQuery right? Sadly that's not an option because I can't guarantee the ID is unique on the view.

Comment: Old question is old but, for clarity, [angular.element()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) is an AngularJS method, not jQuery. Under the hood angular.element() is actually jqLite. However, if jQuery is loaded before AngularJS it will replace the jqLite implementation with jQuery... making angular.element() be equivalent to jQuery's $() under the hood of angular.

Comment: All that said, not being able to guarantee unique IDs represents a flawed design. And using angular.element() is just as likely to fail due to multiple IDs because it is no more limited to the current angular scope than native js methods.